# DFT trigonometric interpolation of $\log(x+1)$

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-series

I am hoping that someone could explain to be a concept of trigonometric interpolation and why the it looks as follows for $\ln(x+1)$. I am not sure of the understanding as to why there is such imperfection when plotted over the interval $[0,2\pi]$. The first result is as follows

[image]

Essentially, I used a sample of 16 abscissae values for the function mentioned above. Even more puzzling to me is the second case when there is a change of conditions to the following, $h(t) = f(t) 0\le t < 2\pi$ and $h(t) = f(4\pi - t), 2\pi \le t < 4\pi$, i get a much better results with a much lower error as follows.

[image]

Thus, I'm not sure how a slight change relates to such a significant improvement in the end results and why there was a large fall off in my DFT interpolant for the first 2 cases. Could someone please explain ? I would appreciate any advice, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first picture, the periodic function you approximate has a jump at the end of the interval. Look for Gibbs phenomenon to get a name for the oscillations of the Fourier sums at a jump.

In the second, the first half of the approximation seems suspect. The Fourier sums should be as symmetric as the function is. Since the function is continuous and has only two kinks, convergence should be uniform.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so is it due to the fact that the function no longer has a jump and goes to 0 at the end which allows for a much better result in the second case ?

Comment: Yes. Plot in both cases more than one period to have the jumps and kinks inside the plot to get a "more natural" view of it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to see where I made the error in the plot before the 2nd kind. So yes, now it interpolates even better from the 1 period plots.

Comment: Hello, could you share your code of these graphs? I've been struggling with that, thank you so much.

Comment: @CharlesSeife : I do not have code for this case, my answer is based on the theoretical behavior of the Fourier series and standard examples like saw tooth, rectangle and triangle wave.  You might want to ask your own question, depending on the nature of it it may be more on topic here, on scicomp.SE or on stackoverflow. For instance, with working code but wrong results it is a toss-up between math.SE or scicomp.SE.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for your reply, best.